# Get the whole innerHTML (parent + child)

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, innerhtml

On a js script, I have a div which I add dynamically some childs.
So from the beginning, I can't know how many childs my div will contains.

When I try to get the innerHTML of my div container, I only obtains the html of the div. Not the html of the node.

How can I get the innerHTML of the whole components, through the childs ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('MyId').outerHTML
```

This gets all the html of the element, inside and itself.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

---

`.outerHTML` for outer, `.innerHTML` for inner.

Answer (score 2):

Using `outerHTML` will do the trick.

```
document.getElementById('YourId').outerHTML
```